# In Qt how to add folder to project which has a shell script to run?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt c++ project in which I want to add a folder which has a bash script which I want to run with Qt. The folder has many sub directories with jar files which will run from the shell script. I will then use macdeployqt so keeping the folder separate is not an option. So haw do I add the folder and run the shell script in it ?

Comment: [What is the question?](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Sorry, check again. I want to know how to add the folder and run the shell script from it and not change the folder structure.

Comment: "add a folder" to what?

Comment: To the project so that I can use the files inside it.